# How to stop a MFC/win32 control re-painting

Tags: mfc, winapi, repaint, cricheditctrl

I have a CRichEditCtrl, and an algorithm works on its contents in-place, iterating through the contents and making changes. This seems to cause it to re-paaint every time, which causes flickering and a noticeable time to complete the operation, especially if the control starts scrolling.
I wondered if there's a neat way for me to stop it repainting for a period. It's actually a custom subclass of CRichEditCtrl in use so I was thinking something like:

```
void MyCustomEditCtrl::DoAlgorithm()
{
 enableRepaint(false);
 ...
 //to the actual work
 ...
 enableRepaint(true);
}
```

What's the neatest approach? A custom on-paint handler which does nothing when an operation is in progress? Or can repainting actually be disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used the function but it looks like you want to look at [CWnd::SetRedraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btaacw58(VS.80).aspx).